# IEnumerable to string delimited with commas?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ado.net, datatable

I have a DataTable that returns

```
IDs
,1
,2
,3
,4
,5
,100
,101
```

I want to convert this to single string value, i.e:

```
,1,2,3,4,5,100,101
```

How can i rewrite the following to get a single string

```
var _values = _tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x);
```

Comment: Check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: It is unclear - what data is returened? Do you have DataRows, and a column of ID? Also, there is confusion over the commas - is it possible they exist in the data base and are already present, or should you add them?

Comment: Thank you to all kind hearted

Comment: `Select(x => x);` makes absolutely no sense, especially in your case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert IEnumerable<string> to one comma separated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481964/how-to-convert-ienumerablestring-to-one-comma-separated-string)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
var singleString = string.Join(",", _values.ToArray() );
```

Comment: Do you need to call ToArray() on _values?

Comment: Simplest solution, I was about to answer that but you'll need to add .ToArray() on _values.

Comment: @ck It depends on exactly what the input data are. Just replace `","` by `String.Empty` if the commas are already in the data.

Comment: @Julien N - I'm just returning the favour, except my answer produces the right result...

Comment: @ck I guess it's a matter of interpretation. I read the commas as peculiar to the OP's formatting rather than being part of the data. In any case, `string.Join` is probably the simplest method of achieving the desired result.

Comment: On .Net 4 `Join` and `Concat` take `IEnumerable`, and you don't need `ToArray`. So, it depends.

Answer (score 12):

Write an extension method such as

```
public static String AppendAll(this IEnumerable<String> collection, String seperator)
{
    using (var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        var builder = new StringBuilder().Append(enumerator.Current);

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            builder.Append(seperator).Append(enumerator.Current);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

and assuming the result of your previous expression is IEnumerable<String>, call:

```
var _values = _tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x).AppendAll(String.Empty);
```

Comment: Apologies for the extras in that extension method - it's one I use quite often to join strings together which suits this case.

Comment: And why the downvote - I know there's extra stuff in there that may not be needed for the question, but it works.

Comment: @Alex - the framework has string.Join, which you might find useful. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx

Comment: @Winston: I'm aware of String.Join. I would of course use it if the source of the data was an array. String.Join requires an array, which has to be held entirely in memory. The array is then copied to the String, again in memory. The memory requirements for String.Join are therefore more than what I have written, which iterates through the items in a sequence one by one and appends them to a string. String.Join is another way which involves a memory requirements/complexity tradeoff.

Comment: Alex - your are a bit outdated on that one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx . Also, it is too early to think about performances, certainly without profiling. What if the data in question is very small, or already in an array?

Comment: @Kobi - thanks, that's good to know - we're still on .NET 3.5 here.

Comment: @Kobi - I was simply discussing the potential tradeoffs, and why my approach was still a valid one. I guess the fact that String.Join takes an enumerable in .NET 4.0 proves that smarter people than me agree.

Answer (score 5):

```
 String.Join(
      ",",
      _tbl.AsEnumerable()
          .Select(r => r.Field<int>("ID").ToString())
          .ToArray())
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var _values = _tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x);
string valueString = _values.ToList().Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
```

Comment: You forgot the separator. a + separator + b

Comment: There is no separator required by the OP

Comment: +1 but why the two steps and call to `ToList`? Why not just `_tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);`?

Comment: In theory, correct. In fact - a number of mistakes. `Select(x => x)` makes not sense because `AsEnumerable()` already makes table `IEnumerable<DataRow`. `ToList()` makes no sense, `Aggregate()` is a member if `IEnumerable<T>` not `List<T>`

Comment: I got the result when i execute _tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>(columnName)).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b) (I am working on Typed DataSet)

Comment: @csharpbaby: `Aggregate((a, b) => a + b)` in your case will do the same as `Sum()` - sum all numbers together. However in your original post you said that you need a string, separated by comma. So `String.Join(",", array)` is what you need

Comment: And `a + b` with a & b being strings is absolutely not processor / memory performant (`"+"` creates a new string for each iteration)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with general `Array` type and i solved it as follows

```
string GetMembersAsString(Array array)
{
    return string.Join(",", array.OfType<object>());
}
```

Note that call `OfType<object>()` is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/archive/p/morelinq/) extension

```
var singleString = _values.ToDelimitedString(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat with this:

```
String output = "";
_tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(x => output += x).ToArray(); 
// output now contains concatenated string
```

Note `ToArray()` or similar is needed to force the query to execute.

Another option is

```
String output = String.Concat(_tbl.AsEnumerable().Select(x=>x).ToArray());
```

Comment: @Winston - There is no separator required, reread the question.

Comment: Second option : `String output = String.Concat(_tbl.AsEnumerable().ToArray());` would do the same, no ? (without the `Select`)