# Selecting ToString() on a String object does not return the actual String

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, lambda

I'm using MVC, and one of my models is `FormElementTypes`, which has an `int ID` and `string Name`.  When I'm attempting to select the `Name` property with Lambda, it doesn't return the actual string of the property.

example

```
foreach (FormElements e in Model.FormElements)
{
    string field = Model.FormElementTypes.Where(f => f.ID == e.FormElementTypesID).Select(f => f.Name).ToString();
}
```

The `Name` property I should be selecting should have the value of `text`.  But when I write it out it spits: `` System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[Scholar.Models.FormElementTypes,System.String] ``

What am I doing wrong, and how do I get the `Name` property string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IEnumerable to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414263/ienumerable-to-string)

Comment: That is perfectly right. You are not using ToString() on Name property, you are using it on a .Select() which is System.Linq.Enumerable ...

Comment: @mjwills possibly?  The syntax and what they were doing is so different than mine that I wouldn't say so, even if the issue under the hood could technically be the same.  Given that I'm not very good at this, I need to operate off of context that is similar to what I'm doing.

Comment: Try `string field = Model.FormElementTypes.Where(f => f.ID == e.FormElementTypesID).Select(f => f.Name).FirstOrDefault()`;

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because you are invoking ToString() on an Enumerable object
which is a collection object. 
You will need to iterate over the collection.
you can read more about the where function in Linq [in here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
foreach (FormElements e in Model.FormElements)
        {
            var fields = Model.FormElementTypes.Where(f => f.ID == e.FormElementTypesID);
            if (fields != null) {
                foreach (var field in fields) {
                    string s = field.Name.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I see, so even though it's a single entity, I still need to iterate over this.  I will try this out and report back, thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3066571, according to your code it is not a single entity but a collection of entitites.

Comment: you are welcome and I'll wait to hear the report but what's important to understand is that it's not a single entity, the system.Linq method signature 
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
 this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
 Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate
)
 returns a IEnumerable, which is a collection base type:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

it normal to have this probleme beaucause you try to convert an IEnumerable to String which is impossible .

best regards .

please try this code  :

```
foreach (FormElements e in Model.FormElements)
{
    string field = Model.FormElementTypes.Where(f => f.ID == e.FormElementTypesID).Select(f => f.Name).FirstOrDefault<string>();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You meant to call `ToList()` rather than `ToString()` to execute the query

```
 var model = Model.FormElementTypes.Where(f => f.ID == e.FormElementTypesID).Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

Just get the entity like

```
 var modelName = Model.FormElementTypes.Where(f => f.ID == e.FormElementTypesID)
                                       .Select(f => f.Name)
                                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You cannot assign a `List<T>` to a `string`

Comment: @series0ne obviously not and so pointed that he probably wants to just execute the query