# System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#

The task is: A sequence of positive integer values integerList is given.
Get sequence of string representations of only odd integerList values and sort in ascending
order.
This is my code:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Task5(IEnumerable<int> integerList)
    {
        var result = from item in integerList
                     where item % 2 != 0
                     orderby item descending
                     select item;
        return result.Cast<string>();
    }
```

But I see this message every time, when try to start tests: System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: use `.ToString()` method instead of `Cast`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IEnumerable to string delimited with commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414263/ienumerable-to-string-delimited-with-commas)

Comment: Since this looks like homework, I'd recommend taking this opportunity to learn how to read error messages and use a debugger. If you're using Visual Studio, you can [attach a debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019) and run the code, and it should show you exactly where the problem is: the `result.Cast<string>()` expression. Then you can look up (click on and press F12) the `Enumerable.Cast` method and see why it might throw that exception.

Comment: does your assignment mention how to handle any duplicate [odd] numbers?

Comment: Also, every answer here, including the original code posted, is sorting the values in **descending** order but the description of the task clearly says **ascending** order.  ```descending``` should be probably be removed from the code

Answer (score 2):

Don't cast, use .ToString() instead

```
  public static IEnumerable<string> Task5(IEnumerable<int> integerList)
    {
        var result = from item in integerList
                     where item % 2 != 0
                     orderby item descending
                     select item.ToString();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` is a collection of *integers*, not *strings*.  And you can't directly cast integers to strings.  But you can call `.ToString()` on them.  So you can use something like `.Select()` to project them into a new collection using that operation.  For example:

```
return result.Select(r => r.ToString());
```

Though it's probably worth examining whether this method *should* return a collection of strings when the source data is integers.  Why not just return the collection of integers instead?  Seems cleaner:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Task5(IEnumerable<int> integerList)
{
    return from item in integerList
           where item % 2 != 0
           orderby item descending
           select item;
}
```

It's difficult to say for certain because "Task5" doesn't exactly describe the operation being performed in any detail.  But the method is *receiving* integers and it looks like the intent is to simply modify that collection, so it makes sense that it would *return* integers.

Then it would be up to the consuming code to convert them to strings if it needs strings for some purpose outside the scope of this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static List<string> Task5(IEnumerable<int> integerList)
    {
        var result = from item in integerList
                     where item % 2 != 0
                     orderby item ascending
                     select item;
        List<int> mylist = result.ToList();
        return mylist.ConvertAll(x => x.ToString());
    }


    public static IEnumerable<string> Task5(IEnumerable<int> integerList)
    {
        var result = from item in integerList
                     where item % 2 != 0
                     orderby item ascending
                     select item.ToString();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This definitely sounds like a homework assignment to me as well... if so, perhaps the name Task5 is a requirement of the assignment.  If not, then as @David suggested, the method name should reflect what operation the method performs (e.g. `FindOddNumbersAscending()`)

Here's what I believe is the correct implementation based on the description of the assignment and also mirroring the feedback above:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> FindOddNumbersAscending(IEnumerable<int> integerList)
{
    return from item in integerList
           where item % 2 != 0
           orderby item
           select item.ToString();
}
```

This can be taken slightly farther to protect against null input as well as removing any duplicates (if that's desirable; note the switch to fluent syntax rather than query syntax for removing duplicates):

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> FindOddNumbersAscending(IEnumerable<int> integerList)
{
    return integerList is null
        ? Enumerable.Empty<string>()
        : integerList
            .Where(item => item % 2 != 0)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(item => item)
            .Select(item => item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I should also note that I share the same concern @David had about transforming the numbers to strings.  That definitely feels like something consuming code should be concerned with and not a side effect of this operation.  That said, it all depends on the parameters of the assignment/task.